# Filtering Alert Manager Alerts with Kubernetes Namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, slack, prometheus-alertmanager

As of Now,
We have Promethues and Alert Manager configured in K8's cluster and the alerts are getting pushed to slack channel.

In our K8's Cluster,
Dynamically Few Namespaces gets Created and pods will be launched.

Can we disable the slack alert notifications from the pods which are dynamically created in the namespaces?

Comment: How do you identify a pod was dynamically created? Do you have a label in the metric that can be used in filter?

Comment: Planning to use namespace regex. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes. Something like `metric{namespace=~".*dynamic.*"}

Comment: Thanks, Can you point me to any examples.

Comment: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#instant-vector-selectors

Comment: you can just silence the notifications in the alert manager then when you silence it there you don't get notifications in the slack

Comment: @SaiChandiniRouthu I am not planning to do it that way.
We cannot keep silencing all the alerts manually from the UI.

I want to filter the alerts by Namespaces and Severity.